# How to input multiple values in python?

Tags: python, function, input, keyword-argument

I have the following function

```
def score(midterm, final, practice, *assignments, **quiz):
    a = 0.25 * midterm
    b = 0.25 * final
    c = 0.2 * practice
    i=0
    d = 0
    for assignment in assignments:
        d += assignment
        i += 1
    d = d/i
    d = 0.05 * d
    for q in quiz:
        e = 0.25 * quiz[q]

    return a+b+c+d+e
```

but i have a problem, i don't know how to input multiple values. if i use coding then i can write it like this
`print(score(77, 65, 88, 75, 81, 80, quiz = 82))`

I want the user to input the argument values. for the 'assignments' argument, it's an uncertain number. it can 1/2/3/more values before keyword-argument. anyone can tell me how?

Comment: Take a look at `str.split()`...

Comment: Do you want the user to input the keyword arguments as well? What should that look like? If not, then this is a duplicate of [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](/q/7378091/4518341).

Comment: Beside the point, but `e` is reset on every iteration, which seems incorrect. Also, setting up `d` is really over-complicated. You could just do `d = 0.05 * statistics.mean(assignments)`

Answer (score 0):

It actually works in a similar way for the input. You need to split the input on for e.g a space and convert it to int. Then python will assign the respective values to each variable:

```
midterm, final, practice, *assignments = map(int, input('Enter grades: ').split(' '))
```